# Pre-validation plugin on annotations entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I wrote a pre-validation plugin on the update of the annotation entity to stop the user from updating a specific note on the account entity based on some criteria.  Now, the problem with this is that once the exception is thrown and the message is displayed to the user, that transaction is cancelled.  However, the text that he has already written on that specific note record, does not get reverted and the moment the user tabs out of it, the pre-validation plugin on the update of the annotation entity is triggered again. This way, it goes into an endless loop and the error message keeps displaying to the user till the time he goes and closes the form.  How is it possible to have the page refreshed after the plugin error message is displayed or is there a way that the text on the page can be reverted so that the plugin is not triggered again?

Comment: Interesting Catch 22...

Comment: Is the error happening on the Save of the form?

Answer (score 0):

i think that is not possible you should use:

```
 if (context.Depth > 1){ return; } //To Avoid Multiple Trigger Of Same Update Plugin.
```